# How can i build a new array from object array elements in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, arrays

i'm using `vb.net` i have the following object array that i'm trung to extract all the true value from give it a name and add it to an array 
here is the object array 
[image]

this is what i have tried so far :

```
  Dim myarray() As String
        Dim number As Integer = 0
        If resultArray(0).BolComment Then

            myarray(number) = "comment"
            number = number + 1
        End If
        If resultArray(0).BolComplete Then

            myarray(number) = "complete"
            number = number + 1
        End If
        If resultArray(0).BolFinished Then

            myarray(number) = "Finished"
            number = number + 1
        End If
        If resultArray(0).BolOutCome Then

            myarray(number) = "OutCome"
            number = number + 1
        End If
        If resultArray(0).BolStatred Then

            myarray(number) = "Started"
            number = number + 1
        End If
        If resultArray(0).BolUser Then

            myarray(number) = "User"
            number = number + 1
        End If
```

this is giving me an error : *the variable has been used before*

**Question** how can i extract all the items that have the `true` value and `push` it to a new array `with` giving it a new `name` 
Thanks

Comment: Any reason not to use a `List(Of String)`? It'll make your code significantly simpler...

Comment: to be honest i don't know how to do this... Thanks

Comment: What line is throwing the error?  You know you have resultArray(x) and resultArray(0)?

Comment: @Blam  i change it to illustrate

Comment: I see no change.  Which line is throwing the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are not initializing the array to a specific size, nor are you re-sizing it each time you add a new item.  However, it would be better to just use the `List(T)` class:

```
Dim list As New List(Of String)()
If resultArray(x).BolComment Then
    list.Add("comment")
End If
If resultArray(0).BolComplete Then
    list.Add("complete")
End If
If resultArray(0).BolFinished Then
    list.Add("Finished")
End If
If resultArray(0).BolOutCome Then
    list.Add("OutCome")
End If
If resultArray(0).BolStatred Then
    list.Add("Started")
End If
If resultArray(0).BolUser Then
    list.Add("User")
End If
```

Then, if you need it as an actual array, do this:

```
Dim myarray() As String = list.ToArray()
```